# Passing headers (or other settings) from Sinatra through Puma

Tags: ruby, cors, rack, puma, response-headers

I am trying to learn how to develop a simple web app using pure Ruby. I have a simple backend service which I created as a Sinatra app. While developing it, I noticed the frontend (a simple HTML/JS static site) would not communicate with it because of CORS policies. So I looked into how to pass headers from Sinatra.

I came across [sinatra-cors](https://github.com/jdesrosiers/sinatra-cors). I set it up as instructed and my app looks like this (abbreviated):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cors'

  set :allow_origin, '*'
  set :allow_methods, 'GET,HEAD,POST'
  set :allow_headers, 'content-type,if-modified-since,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin'
  set :expose_headers, 'content-disposition'
  set :allow_credentials, true

  post '/' do
    [...]
  end
```

When I run it with `ruby app.rb`, it works perfectly. Frontend can communicate and CORS policies are observed.

Now, I want to set up the service for a production environment. For that, I want to use Puma. So with Puma, I have a `config.ru` which looks like this:

```
require File.expand_path('app', File.dirname(__FILE__))
run WebApp
```

and I modified my `app.rb` to look like this (again abbreviated):

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/cors'

class WebApp < Sinatra::Application

  set :allow_origin, '*'
  set :allow_methods, 'GET,HEAD,POST'
  set :allow_headers, 'content-type,if-modified-since,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin'
  set :expose_headers, 'content-disposition'
  set :allow_credentials, true

  post '/' do
    [...]
  end
end
```

basically, wrapped the app in a class, and call it from the `config.ru`. When I run this by running `puma` in the directory, the service comes up, but headers are no longer passed back. Whenever I try to hit the backend, I get:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4567/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This was the error I was getting before I originally set up the headers. So it seems pretty clear to me that the `set` parameters are being ignored.

So, this seems like a simple matter, but I have not been able to find a proper answer: **How do I make Puma respect the 'set' parameters? Or alternatively, how do I achieve the same desired result?**

It seems clear to me that I am missing a very simple thing, but I cannot figure out what exactly it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are just missing `register Sinatra::Cors` in your class.

```
class WebApp < Sinatra::Application
  register Sinatra::Cors # Add this line.

  set :allow_origin, '*'
  # etc.
```

Comment: That did the trick! Now I must go learn what `register` does. Thanks a lot for the quick response!